# The Function Of Displayinfo() does not work it says the file is not created. The Purpose of this Function Is To read a Specific Lines

Tags: c, function, file, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Max 500

typedef struct
{
    char Matricule[50];
    char Model[30];
    char Price[30];
    int KilometrePerHour;
    char Etat[50];
}
Voiture;

Voiture info[Max];
void stockinfo();
void Saveinfo();
void Displayinfo();
void displayAll();
int n;

void stockinfo()
{
    int i;
    printf("How many Cars You Want To Add ? \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter The Matricule : \n");
        scanf("%s", info[i].Matricule);
        printf("Enter The Module : \n");
        scanf("%s", info[i].Model);
        printf("Enter The Price : \n");
        scanf("%s", info[i].Price);
        printf("Enter The Kilometere Per Hour : \n");
        scanf("%d", &info[i].KilometrePerHour);
        printf("Enter The Case : \n");
        scanf("%s", info[i].Etat);
    }
}

void Saveinfo()
{
    FILE * save;
    save = fopen("CarsParc.doc", "a");
    if (save == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file is Not Created Succefully..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fprintf(save, "\t\tThe Information Of %s Car..\n", info[i].Model);
            fprintf(save, "The Matricule :%s\n", info[i].Matricule);
            fprintf(save, "The Model :%s\n", info[i].Model);
            fprintf(save, "The Price :%s\n", info[i].Price);
            fprintf(save, "The Kilometre/h :%d\n", info[i].KilometrePerHour);
            fprintf(save, "Tha Case (New/Used) :%s\n", info[i].Etat);
            fprintf(save, "\n\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(save);
}

/*i meant this function*/
void Displayinfo()
{
    FILE * save;
    save = fopen("CarsParc.doc", "r");
    if (save == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file is Not Created Succefully..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char T[100];
        char mtrcl[100];
        do {    fgets(T, 100, save);
            printf("Enter The Matricule : \n");
            scanf("%s", mtrcl);
            int i;
            if (strcmp(T, mtrcl) == 0)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
                {
                    fgets(T, 100, save);
                    printf("%s", T);
                }
            }
        } while (strcmp(T, mtrcl) != 0);
        fclose(save);
    }
}

void displayAll()
{
    FILE * save;
    save = fopen("CarsParc.doc", "r");
    if (save == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file is Not Created Succefully..\n");
    }
    else
    {
        char copy;
        do {    copy = fgetc(save);
            printf("%c", copy);
        } while (copy != EOF);
        fclose(save);
    }
}

main()
{
    /*code */
    int choice;
    printf("\t\t Welcome To Cars Parc : \n");
    printf("1-Add Car : |Click One.. | \n");
    printf("2-Search for Specific Car : |Click Two.. |\n");
    printf("3-See All The informations : |Click Three..|\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    system("cls");
    do {
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            stockinfo();
            Saveinfo();
            system("cls");
            int back;
            printf("The Informations Of This %s Car in Saved Now..\n", info[Max].Model);
            printf("To Back To The Menue Click 0 ..\n");
            scanf("%d", &back);
            if (back == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                main();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("This is The End Of The Programme..");
            }
        }
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            Displayinfo();
            int back;
            printf("\n\n\n");
            printf("To Back To The Menue Click 0 ..\n");
            scanf("%d", &back);
            if (back == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                main();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("This is The End Of The Programme..");
            }
        }
        if (choice == 3)
        {
            displayAll();
            int back;
            printf("\n\n\n");
            printf("To Back To The Menue Click 0 ..\n");
            scanf("%d", &back);
            if (back == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                main();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("This is The End Of The Programme..");
            }
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
}
```

Comment: This code is very hard to read, being double-spaced and lacking indentation. One thing I notice is that `main()` is calling `main();` which is poor practice.

Comment: Change `printf("The file is Not Created Succefully..\n");` to [perror("Unable to open file");](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).  You need to determine exactly *WHY* "fopen()" failed.  Post back what you find.

Comment: ok sir. i'll do it

Comment: Why do all your functions return `void` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for reading ("r").  This will not create it if is does not exist.  You need to use the appropriate mode (w or a).

From the man page:

```
``r''   Open for reading.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of
             the file.  Fail if the file does not exist.

     ``w''   Open for writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of
             the file.  Create the file if it does not exist.

     ``a''   Open for writing.  The stream is positioned at the end of the
             file.  Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the
             then current end of file, irrespective of any intervening
             fseek(3) or similar.  Create the file if it does not exist.
```

Comment: If you look further, you'll see the OP is attempting to read: `fgets(T, 100, save);`.  The key issue is that the OP needs to check for error (he's doing that - he's checking for "NULL"), and then determine *WHY* the error occurred (e.g. read [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) or call [perror()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).